# Visual Studio dump analysis: how to find the command which retrieves source code from source control

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, windbg, visual-sourcesafe

In my company, people used to work with Visual SourceSafe, but some years ago they decided to start working with GIT.
I started working here some months ago, and as such I've never set up a Visual SourceSafe environment.

While debugging dumps from older versions, this is giving problems: it seems that the dumps (taken using `procdump`) contain commands for retrieving source code, using Visual SourceSafe.

I've just installed Visual SourceSafe, and I was hoping that this would make it possible to get the older versions of the source code, but this is not the case. (For your information, even after having installed Visual SourceSafe, I don't see any SourceSafe information in Visual Studio's "Team Explorer - Connect" window)

(the original question contains quite some investigation information, which seems to be obsolete now that the answer of this question is known)

Comment: What did you learn when you asked the people already at your company and who are working on other dumps?

Comment: @AdrianHHH: that's exactly the problem: the one who works here the longest has a system which is working, and another one (who arrived here after me) has the same problem as me. The oldest one has no clue anymore on how his system has been set up (it's already configured more than 6 years, so I can't blame him for not remembering), but as a result me and that other collegue are completely stuck. Hence he question of my boss to try to fix it and document the solution, in order not to encounter such a situation in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable: the issue is caused because the SourceSafe installation seems not to be complete:

In order to get it working, the following needs to be done:
Add the SourceSafe directory to the `$PATH$` environment variable (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe`)

Create the `$SSDIR$` environment variable in order for SourceSafe to know where to look for the source code (should refer to the directory, containing the `srcsafe.ini` file).

Answer (score 1):

### How things are related

> [...] it seems that the dumps (taken using procdump) contain commands for retrieving source code, using Visual SourceSafe.

A crash dump does not contain commands. It contains version information about the EXE and the DLLs that were loaded. WinDbg and Visual Studio will then look for PDB files which match that version information. The PDB file then contains information about the source code.

To find PDBs, you need a symbol server and/or a local path with symbols.

### SourceSafe

> I've just installed Visual SourceSafe, and I was hoping that this would make it possible to get the older versions of the source code, but this is not the case.

Installing SourceSafe does not help. You'll need to connect to a repository using `Visual SourceSafe Admin` and grant yourself access rights.

[image: Visual SourceSafe Admin]

Then, using Visual SourceSafe (not Admin), map a local folder ("Set working folder") and pull ("Get latest version"). You then have the source code locally and you can instruct your tools to use that path. For WinDbg, `.srcpath` and `.lsrcpath` should be correct.

You might need to get different versions by date if you really want to analyze with source code. To automate this process, you would need a source server, but you would know if you have one.

### The age of the dumps

You say:

> [...] some **years** ago they decided to start working with GIT.

So your source code should be in GIT, not in SourceSafe.

If your crash dump file is so old that it refers to SourceSafe, then consider it as obsolete and take a new dump. If nobody complains about crashes recently, I would no longer care (saying that as a former Test Manager).